# typedef and non-simple type specifiers

Tags: c++, c, language-lawyer

Why is this code invalid?

```
typedef int INT;
unsigned INT a=6;
```

whereas the following code is valid

```
typedef int INT;
static INT a=1;
```

?

As per my understanding `unsigned int` is not a `"simple type specifier"` and so the code is ill-formed. I am not sure though.

Can anyone point to the relevant section of the `Standard` which makes the first code invalid(and the second code valid)?

**EDIT**

Although [Johannes Schaub's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/34509/johannes-schaub-litb) answer seemed to be correct and to the point(he had deleted his answer BTW) I accepted James Curran's answer for its correctness and preciseness.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why would you do that? There's not much reason for that redefinition. `typedef unsigned int UINT;` might make more sense, though....

Comment: Yeah JAB I know that, actually I would never write such code practically. However I am curious why doesn't the first code work? So the question has also been tagged `language-lawyer`.

Comment: I know this is not the primary subject, but you can write "std::make_unsigned<INT>::type"  (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee361636.aspx?ppud=4)

Comment: `typedef int INT;` considered harmful. Along with other ridiculous uses of `typedef`. In short, `typedef int tokenid;` or `typedef int audiosample;` make sense; `typedef int INT;` and `typedef int gint;` are simply pollution of your codebase with crap that makes it harder to reuse.

Comment: If it makes you feel better, just replace `INT` with `tokenid` before answering his question.

Comment: @Dennis: and then the ridiculousness of the question becomes apparent! `unsigned tokenid` makes no sense. `unsigned INT` only "makes sense" to the programmer because `INT` should have been `int` to begin with. I suppose I should have stated this explicitly before.

Comment: @R: and what about the `ridiculousness` of the first line of your last comment? :P

Comment: Really, `unsigned char` makes about as much sense as `unsigned tokenid` does.

Comment: The days of thinking `char` means character in the natural-language sense are long gone (c. 1991, almost 20 years ago). If you think of it in the computing sense of "smallest unit of data" then there's nothing odd about it having signed/unsigned variants. On the other hand there's no such thing as `signed wchar_t` and `unsigned wchar_t` because these are intended for use as actual character ordinals. Similarly in the `tokenid` example, once you've chosen the type for `tokenid` it makes little sense to have signed/unsigned variants of it and it probably shouldn't even be used as an integer...

Comment: The point is that there's nothing intrinsically ridiculous about a type other than primitives having signed and unsigned variants.  The meaning of the type is what determines this.  If you might have "typedef signed int SignedBlah" and "typedef unsigned int UnsignedBlah", why not just have "typedef int Blah" and then go "unsigned Blah" as needed? Is this wise? Probably not.  But its hardly ridiculous either.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

`typedef`s are not like macros.  They are not just text substitution.  A Typedef creates a new typename.

Now when you say `unsigned int`, the `unsigned` isn't a modifier which is tacked onto the `int`. `unsigned int` is the complete typename; it just happens to have a space in it.

So, when you say `typedef int INT;`  then `INT` is the complete typename.  It can't be modified.

`static` (like `const`) is a storage class specifier. It's not actually part of the type name.

Comment: C++0x standard section 3.9.1 paragraph 3 lists the unsigned integral types and supports your answer.  `unsigned int` is a type that has a space in the name.  `unsigned` is not listed as a modifier to another type to magically make it non-negative.

Answer (score 11):

- 7.1.1 : static is a storage class specifier. It can be placed before
  any type.
- 7.1.5 : what is a type specifier (unsigned can be combined with char,
  long, short, or int)

Comment: `unsigned` can also be a type all by itself.

Comment: And qualifies implicitely int type

Comment: +1 not quite elaborative, but correct and if he's got any knowledge of standardese, i suspect these section numbers will help him.

Comment: @Johannes: Yes his answer is correct but I have accepted James' answer because his answer is elaborative as well. BTW why did you delete your answer? :)

Answer (score 2):

Don't forget that typedef-ing is not like macro-defining; in your example, it seems like if you think your INT should be seen like a literal `int`. From the compiler point of view, typedef defines type-aliases, but this is not seen at "syntax" level (typedef-ed types are like "native" types at the syntax level); and since at that level unsigned is allowed before char long short or int only, your `unsigned INT` is seen like a "type" ("different" from char, long, short, int) preceded by `unsigned`.